# Facing problem while displaying data from the SQLite database to a textview

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get data from the SQLite database and display the output from I a text view. The program is not crashing but I am unable to display the data.

The data is being fetched as it is showing up on the log.

```
try{
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= this.openOrCreateDatabase("User",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (name VARCHAR,age INT(3))");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name,age) VALUES ('rob',34)");
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO users (name,age) VALUES ('Souvik',20)");

        Cursor c= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users",null);

        int nameIndex=c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int ageIndex=c.getColumnIndex("age");

        c.moveToFirst();


        while (c!=null){
            x.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
            x.add(Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
            Log.i("name",c.getString(nameIndex));
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        txt.setText(x.get(2));


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written an endless `while` loop because `c` is not and will never be `null`.
Remove this line:

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

and change the loop to this:

```
while (c.moveToNext){
    x.add(c.getString(nameIndex));
    x.add(Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));
    Log.i("name",c.getString(nameIndex));
}
```

I assume that `x` is a `List` where you store the results.
So after the loop ends you will have 4 items in the `List`.
With this line:

```
txt.setText(x.get(2));
```

you set the text of the `TextView` to the 3d item of the `List`.
Of course this will work if the database is created, the table is created and the `INSERT` statements do not fail.
Since all your code is inside a `try/catch` block the app will will not crash if there is a problem.

Comment: now the app is not loading, there is no log and the app is also not showing the appbar, It is freezing

Comment: Read the last lines of my answer. Your code is inside a try/catch block. Remove it and read the error log to find what is causing the problem.